# Empty JSON values (LWC)

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Hi guys
I'm trying to get some "hardcoded" values from an apex Method, but when I write a console.log it's comming empty. 
[image]

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
@wire(getValues)
wiredValues({error, data})
     if(data) {
     console.log("Data::::::",data);
     this.getVal = JSON.stringify(data);
     } else if(error){
           this.error = error;
           this.getVal = undefined;
           console.log("No values");
     }
```

Here's my apex method(I'm trying to make kind of "fake" callout but i'm not sure if im right):

```
public without sharing class getSomeValues {
       @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
       public static List<wrapVal> getWrapVal() {

        HttpResponse request = new HttpResponse();
        request.setBody('{"Values": ["1000", "2000", "3000", "4000", "5000"]}');
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) 
        JSON.deserializeUntyped(request.getBody());
        List<Object> sumVal = (List<Object>) results.get('Values');
        List<wrapVal> newLstValues = new List<wrapVal>();

        for (Object getValues : sumVal ) {
             wrapVal newLstValue = new wrapVal();
             newLstValue.nwValue = String.valueOf(getValues);
             newLstValues.add(newLstValue);
             System.debug("getValues::::::"+ newLstValue.nwValue);
       }
        return newLstValues;
  }

  public class wrapVal {
  public String nwValue { get; set; }
  }
```

Debug: 
[image]

So idk what i'm doing wrong, if can share with me some advice or documentation it'd be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to decorate the properties of the class wrapVal with @AuraEnabled. Otherwise LWC won't receive them.

```
 public class wrapVal {
  @AuraEnabled
  public String nwValue { get; set; }
  }
```